# Visual Studio 2019 Angular template not working?

Tags: angular, visual-studio

Create a new ASP.Net Core Web Application project and choose the "Angular" template. New project appears but app does not build. Get error:

```
Error occurred while restoring NuGet packages:
The local source 'D:\Development\Repos\OptiCloud\3rdParty' doesn't exist.
```

And indeed that file does not exist. Using Visual Studio 2019 16.3.1, not preview. Anyone else hitting this problem?

Comment: do you have npm configured to retrieve packages from this directory? what happens if you go straight to clientApp directory and run npm install from there - do you get an error!

Comment: Hey Felix - thanks for the response!

"clientApp directory and run npm install from there" - this works fine and npm install completes with no error

"do you have npm configured to retrieve packages from this directory" I have not configured npm at all. Merely installed it as part of node, then got Visual Studio to create the new project for me...

Comment: Interesting... what is OptiCloud? looks like some application that you have on your machine and that set up their own repo. Maybe, for testing, just create and empty folder - so that it doesn't complain?